# undefined in response of async function

Tags: typescript, react-native, promise, ecmascript-6

I got a problem when trying to use async method.

I have a authServices containing loginWithCredential async function

```
async loginWithCredential(username, password){
    var data = {username: username, password: password};
    api.post('/api/users/login', data)
        .then(successCallback, errorCallback)

    function successCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

    function errorCallback(error){
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in my store, I try to get data

```
@action login (user, password) {
    this.isAuthenticating = true;
    // more code above, here is the relevant setting of token
    return authServices.loginWithCredential(user, password).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);

    },function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

The problem is that the response in my store is always undefined since it has been triggered before the returning of service. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Just found the solution. I've forgotten to add return in async function. It should be "return api.post('..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async loginWithCredential(username, password) {
    var data = {username: username, password: password};
    const {data} = await api.post('/api/users/login', data)
    return data;
}
@action async login (user, password) {
    this.isAuthenticating = true;
    // more code above, here is the relevant setting of token
    return await authServices.loginWithCredential(user, password)
}
```

you use `await` in `async` functions. otherwise, return a promise.

you **CANNOT** return in a callback function, it doesn't mean you return a value in the `login` function, it's not the context.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use await keyword with async and you can put await only when your function has async keyword , try this:

```
async loginWithCredential(username, password){
    var data = {username: username, password: password};
   await api.post('/api/users/login', data)
        .then(successCallback, errorCallback)

    function successCallback(response) {
        return response.data;
    }

    function errorCallback(error){
        console.error(error);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That alone won't help. `loginWithCredential` still needs to return something.

Comment: No need await, just need to return data from api.post